# Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x5B19A9E8  нарушение прав доступа при чтении

Tags: c++

Ошибка в деструкторе, объясните, пожалуйста (файл FirstClass.cpp). Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x5B19A9E8  нарушение прав доступа при чтении.

```
FirstClass.h
protected:
    int **Matr;
    int m;
    int n;
    void Create();
public:
    //constr, destr
Matrix() : m(8), n(8) { Create(); }
Matrix(int i) : m(i), n(i) { Create(); }
Matrix(int i, int j) : m(i), n(j) { Create(); }
~Matrix();
//Metods
int& Element(int i, int j);
void MultiplyBy(int x);
void Display();
};
#endif

FirstClass.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "FirstClass.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Matrix::Create()
{
Matr = new int*[m];
for (int z = 0; z < m; z++)
    Matr[z] = new int[n];
}

Matrix::~Matrix()
{
if (Matr)
{
    for (int z = 0; z < m; z++)
    {
        delete[] Matr[z];//////Vetoi stroke
    }
    delete[] Matr;
}
}

int& Matrix::Element(int i, int j)
{
if (i < m && j < n)
    return Matr[i][j];
else
    cout << "Error: 1";
}

 void Matrix::MultiplyBy(int x)
{
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        Matr[i][j] *= x;
}

void Matrix::Display()
{
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cout.width(1);
        cout << Matr[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}
program1.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "FirstClass.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

 struct Tree
{
Tree *l, *r;
Matrix arr;
};

int value = 0;

void Add(Matrix arr, Tree **Node)
{
if ((*Node == NULL))
{
    (*Node) = new Tree;
    (*Node)->l = (*Node)->r = NULL;
    (*Node)->arr = arr;
}
else
    if (value % 2 == 0) Add(arr, &(*Node)->l);
    else Add(arr, &(*Node)->r);
    value++;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
srand(time(0));
const int Razm = 8;
Matrix Mas(Razm, Razm);
for (int i = 0; i < Razm; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < Razm; j++)
        Mas.Element(i, j) = rand() % 2;

cout << "Matrix: " << endl;
Mas.Display();

Tree *MyTree = NULL;
Add(Mas, &MyTree);//sozdali koren`

system("pause");
return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, проблема в том, что вы передаёте матрицу в функцию `Add` *по значению*.

Поскольку у вас нету конструктора копирования, то в копии, попадающей в функцию, тот же экземпляр `Matr`. Когда функция отрабатывает, этот экземпляр `Matr` уничтожается, и убивает память, принадлежащую *внешнему* экземпляру `Matr`!

Вам не стоит копировать матрицу, так как это потенциально дорогая операция. Создавайте матрицу в куче и храните в дереве указатель на неё, чтобы избежать копирования.